# Razor Page routing via DynamicRouteValueTransformer always returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm using a custom dynamic route transformer in an ASPNET Core 5 Razor Pages app. My TransformAsync override is called as expected and returns a custom route to a page, but that page is never loaded, and the request always returns 404. Either Razor pages can't find the page I'm routing to, or it's just ignoring my custom route.

Here's a simple test case. Any tips on what might be wrong, or how I can troubleshoot would be greatly appreciated!

In Startup.Configure(..) I have

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<LaunchPageTransformer>("{**id}");
});
```

My LaunchPageTransformer:DynamicRouteValueTransformer implementation:

```
public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
   return await Task.Run(() =>
   {
       return new RouteValueDictionary()
       {
           { "page", "Test" },
           { "id", "123" }
       };
   });
}
```

In Pages/Test.cshtml I have

```
@page "{id}"
@model Launch.Pages.TestModel
@{
}
```

And in Pages/Test.cshtml.cs:

```
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
   public void OnGet(int? id)
   {
   }
}
```

I'm navigating to localhost:44351/123, which successfully selects my transformer but does nothing with the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 things wrong in your code. Firstly `MapDynamicControllerRoute` is used for selecting a controller action, not for selecting a page handler. What you need to use is `MapDynamicPageRoute`. Secondly the value for `page` route key should be a path starting with `/`. So instead of `"Test"`, you need `"/Test"`.

Here's the final code you need (replacing your code):

```
endpoints.MapDynamicPageRoute<LaunchPageTransformer>("{**id}");
```

Inside your implementation of `LaunchPageTransformer`:

```
return new RouteValueDictionary()
{
    //we need to use a / to prefix the page name here
    { "page", "/Test" },
    { "id", "123" }
};
```

Comment: You gave me a good idea with this post. In my case, I had to do a few additional values because my razor pages are setup using area, but no big deal. here is the representation of the RouteValueDictionary:
`
new RouteValueDictionary
                    {
                        {"area", "Identity" },
                        {"page", "/Account/Login" },
                        {"route", "/Login" }
                    });
`